# One field identical, one field different (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm looking at a table like this:

```
    TABLE NAME: DD
    --------------------------------------
    ID   | EMPLOYEE_ID  |       NAME     |   
    --------------------------------------
    1    |    100       | ABLE           |
    2    |    100       | ABLE           |
    3    |    101       | BAKER          |
    4    |    101       | CHARLIE        |
    5    |    102       | DOG            |
    6    |    102       | EASY           |
    7    |    102       | DOG            |
    --------------------------------------
```

There are thousands of records, every EMPLOYEE_ID is in there at least twice. I am looking for a query that will return all the records where the EMPLOYEE_ID is identical but the NAME is not. So like this:

```
    --------------------------------------
    ID   | EMPLOYEE_ID  |       NAME     |   
    --------------------------------------
    3    |    101       | BAKER          |
    4    |    101       | CHARLIE        |
    5    |    102       | DOG            |
    6    |    102       | EASY           |
    --------------------------------------
```

I've tried this, which should work in theory, but it causes an error due to the temp order running out of space:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM DD A
INNER JOIN DD B
 on A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID
 and A.NAME <> B.NAME
ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: Please can you show us the error ? Also please share table D ?

Comment: Should the second table also be "DD"?

Comment: Edited typo, second table is DD as well. Currently reproducing the error.

Comment: @TrustyphonePueblo you do see that you have 3 answers so far right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the exact result you asked:

```
select min(id) ID
       , EMPLOYEE_ID
       , NAME
from DD
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ( select e_id 
                       from (SELECT name
                                    , count(EMPLOYEE_ID)
                                    , max(EMPLOYEE_ID) e_id
                             FROM DD 
                             group by name) a
                       group by e_id
                       having count(e_id) > 1 )
group by EMPLOYEE_ID
         , NAME;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b7bb303de09fadd43e1c396752d0738)

The **forpas** is correct when he say: "This code is wrong. Check this: dbfiddle.uk/… ". Here is another code:

```
select min(id) ID
       , EMPLOYEE_ID
       , NAME
from DD
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ( SELECT distinct EMPLOYEE_ID e_id
                       FROM DD 
                       group by EMPLOYEE_ID
                       having count(distinct name) > 1 )
group by EMPLOYEE_ID
         , NAME;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2236c327d8bdeb8f55289de0f735aa20)

Result:

[image]

Comment: @TrustyphonePueblo This code is wrong. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02ed6b573ca8c6439c978db630709e6a

Comment: Hi @forpas , thanks for the constructive criticism, I have updated the code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use an aggregating subquery to identify the employee_id values that have more than one name, and then retrieve the entries for those employee_id values.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t AS t1
WHERE t1.employee_id IN (
   SELECT employee_id 
   FROM t 
   GROUP BY employee_id 
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
)
;
```

The possible problem with the query you presented is if employee X has 10 entries with the name "Bob" and 20 entries with the name "Dave", that query will return 200 results for those 30 entries with just two names for one employee. If X also has 5 entries with "Joe", it gets even worse.

If you add a composite index on (employee_id, name), it should improve the performance of almost any query used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select min(t.id) id, t.employee_id, t.name 
from (
  select d.* from DD d
  where exists (
    select 1 from DD
    where employee_id = d.employee_id and name <> d.name
  )
) t  
group by t.employee_id, t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n4U2WJR1zqnEHXmihSMp22/1).
Results:

```
| id  | EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME    |
| --- | ----------- | ------- |
| 3   | 101         | BAKER   |
| 4   | 101         | CHARLIE |
| 5   | 102         | DOG     |
| 6   | 102         | EASY    |
```